# Why can't rsyslogd find libgcc_s.so.1?

Tags: rsyslog, lxc, gcc

Scenario: Running a debootstrapped Ubuntu 11.4 lxc guest on a Ubuntu 12.4 lxc host.

Inside the lxc guest, rsyslogd is constantly crashing with SIGABRT stating:

```
libgcc_s.so.1 must be installed for pthread_cancel to work
0334.380551272:7f4128a84700: 
Signal 6 (SIGABRT) occured, execution must be terminated.
```

I'm not sure why libgcc_s.so.1  cannot be found.  If I run ldconfig -p:

```
$# ldconfig -p | grep libgcc
        libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        libgcc_s.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
```

It is listed. And both of those links are fine.

How do I resolve this problem?